# Android webview goback lost content updated by javascript

Tags: javascript, android, html, webview, cache-control

I'm using `webView` to load some webpages and after calling `goBack()` to get back to the previous page, I found the contents updated by javascript dynamically in previous page was all lost.

So the steps are,

1. Load web page A first
2. The user clicks a button to trigger javascript to display additional text, and then jump to web page B
3. The user clicks hardware back button so I call goBack() to bring the user to web page A again

Now the web page A switched to the default look and have no additional text which means I lost any updates triggered by javascript.

By debugging using Chrome, I saw when calling `goBack()`, the web page A's request status code is shown as "**200 OK** (from cache)", I guess `webView` just cached the previous page's html result and re-displayed it.

How can I prevent the `webView` from re-displaying the cached **HTML**, but instead just let the page A keep where it was before jump to another page?

p.s: The web server set the Cache-Control header as no-cache.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You should show your effort and where you get stuck - what error messages you get, what you have tried and dismissed... SO is not a site for learning basics or getting code written for you.

Comment: @Toxide82 Thanks for the kind suggestion, but I'm kind of stuck and don't know where to investigate, because of cross platform and user experience, I have to use no-cache as the value of Cache-Control, and also use `WebSettings.LOAD_DEFAULT` as cache mode of `WebSettings`, I also did go through all the apis WebSettings provide but couldn't find any helpful information.

Comment: but without seeing your code how are we supposed to see where we could help. I don't know what initialization you already have on the page which could be running even through your going back a page. Also have you tried it with `history.back(-1);` to see if that makes any difference.

Comment: @Toxide82 I guess you mean calling javascript's `history.back(-1)`? It's same with calling `goBack()`. I saw someone talking on the internet that it was how webView worked and could achieve my purpose by implementing multiple webViews to jump around (it's not my option unfortunately), but it was 4~5 years ago, so I'd like to know if it's even possible NOW or if any other hacking ways.